# How do I get the same style for an AppCompat button at different API levels

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a simple button on an activity

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/pick_photo_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onSelectFile"
        android:text="Select Photo"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
         />
```

For some reason the button has different colors on different emulators with distinct API levels.
At API level 23 it looks as it is supposed to be. This is alos how the design view in AndroidStudio shows the preview.

[image]

But on Api level 22 the button has a red color
[image]

Hers is the gradle config:

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.sizzr.sizzr"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
....
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
```

How do I get the buttons styled in an equal manner down to API level 16?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the best structure of your project
- android:text -> use string.xml
- android:textColor -> colors.xml

layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/pick_photo_button"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onSelectFile"
    android:text="Select Photo"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    />
```

style.xml && v21/style.xml

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How can I inherit from Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored in order to get the same styling?

Comment: use the `parent` attribute of the style